# Neo4j Desktop on Mac OS change port number

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

Is there a way to have the Neo4j Desktop run on a port other than 4000?  We have some software that is currently using that port and it is conflicting.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Default port for neo4j is 7474.

Finds `neo4j.conf` file for your installation and edit it to change the port(s). 
Start(Restart) Neo4j.

Comment: It's not Neo4j, but Neo4j Desktop.  It is running the Mac OS app on port 4000.  None of the Neo4j server configs seem to change how the "Desktop" is running.

Comment: This works for Neo4j server as well as Neo4j Desktop. There easy way to change port on Neo4j Desktop. Goto 'manage' option and change port under settings tab. Then click 'Apply'. It will ask to confirm Neo4j restart click restart now.